# set the progress speed of the progress bar to be equal to the time of the percentage counter?

Tags: react-native, progress-bar, settimeout, react-props, progress

how to set the progress speed of the progress bar to be equal to the time of the percentage counter?
the bar is at a very fast speed, while the percentage numbers shown are slowly passing from 1 to 100. I wish the two were at the same speed, as if they were one but one, not distinct elements. Will someone help me with this please?

````
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

class App extends Component {
  **constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {progress: 0,};
  }


  startProgressIndicators() {
    let progress = 0;
    this.setState({progress}, () =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({indeterminate: false});
        setInterval(() => {
          progress += Math.random() + 1 / 100;
          if (progress <= 100) {
            this.state.progress}
          else{
            this.state.progress(false)
          }
          this.setState({progress});
        }, 500);
      },1500 ),
    );
  }**

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}> Progress indicator </Text>
        <View style={{margin: 5}} />
        
       ** <Button
          title="Iniciar"
          onPress={() => this.startProgressIndicators()}
        />**


        <View styles={{}}>
        {`${this.state.progress.toFixed(0)}%`}
        </View>

        <Progress.Bar
         size={50}
         progress={this.state.progress}
         width={200}
          style={{margin: 5, fontSize: 10}}
        />
        
     
       
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    color: '#051923',
    margin: 10,
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});

export default App;

{
  /* <Progress.Bar progress={0.3} width={200} />
<Progress.Pie progress={0.4} size={50} />
<Progress.CircleSnail color={['red', 'green', 'blue']} /> */
}
```
`

**how to set the progress speed of the progress bar to be equal to the time of the percentage counter?
the bar is at a very fast speed, while the percentage numbers shown are slowly passing from 1 to 100. I wish the two were at the same speed, as if they were one but one, not distinct elements. Will someone help me with this please?**
````

Answer (score 0):

`progress` should be a number between 0 and 1.

```
<Text>{`${this.state.progress.toFixed(0)}%`}</Text>

<Progress.Bar progress={this.state.progress/100} />
```